# Is it possible to record action while opening another app on Android?

Tags: android, record

As the title said, I want to know if it is possible to record my action (touch, swipe, etc) on smartphone while I'm using another app. If it is, then how can I do it?

Thank you for reading :D

Comment: May be possible from accessibility service... But you better have a really good reason

Comment: I use it for my mobile presentation app without video streaming. I've read somewhere that we can not do this when the recording app is not on-top.

Comment: That's true, but when you have accessibility permissions you can detect these things as you would have to be able to provide full functionality if you actually were allowing blind people to use the phone

Comment: Can you please give me a clear way how to do it? Or some similar apps that can do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is possible, it would be through an accessibility service as it has access to gesture and tap listening. More information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html

Comment: Thanks for your help :D verry sorry that I don't have enough reputation to vote for your answer :(